# Print reverse pyramid of numbers

Tags: android

I am able to print pyramid like this :

> ```
>    1
>   123
>  12345
> 1234567
> ```

Code i used to print the pyramid of numbers like above is :

```
                int a = 1;
                int b = 4;
                for (int i = 1 ; i <= 4 ; i++){
                    for (int c = 1 ; c <= b - 1 ; c++){
                        text.append("  ");
                    }
                    for (int k = 1 ; k <= a ; k++){
                        String result = String.valueOf(k);
                        text.append(result);
                    }
                    a = a + 2;
                    b--;
                    text.append("\n");
                }
```

but, the issue i am facing is i have to print the same pyramid, but in reverse order like this :

> ```
>  1234567
>   12345
>    123
>     1
> ```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with and what kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: what have you tried so far? What exactly is a problem? Any errors? Or you just want us to do it **instead of you**?

Comment: Change  for (int i = 1 ; i <= 4 ; i++) to  for (int i = 1 ; i >= 4 ; i--)

Comment: i have to print reverse


like this


        1234567
  12345
   123
           1

Comment: Please check your tags, how is this question Android specific?

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
 for (int i = 7; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");

        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int a = 1;
int b = 4;
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    for (int k = a; k >= 1; k--) {
        String result = String.valueOf(k);
        text.append(result);
    }
    for (int c = 1; c <= b - 1; c++) {
        text.append("  ");
    }
    a = a + 2;
    b--;
    text.append("\n");
}

System.out.println(text.reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
 int a = 1;
            int b = 4;
            int m = 4;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                for (int c = 1; c <= m; c++) {
                    text.append("  ");
                }
                for (int k = 1; k <= b; k++) {
                    String result = String.valueOf(k);
                    text.append(result);
                }
                a = a + 2;
                b--;
                m++;
                text.append("\n");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int w = 7;
        System.out.println("Here is your pattern....!!!");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row

            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            //Printing i to rows value at the end of each row

            for (int j = 1; j <=w; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(j+" ");
            }
            w = w - 2;

            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int numberofdigits = 7;
        int numberofdigitsforrow = 0;
        int Emptyspace = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberofdigits; i++)
        {
            numberofdigitsforrow = numberofdigits - i * 2;
            if (numberofdigitsforrow > 0)
            {
                Emptyspace = numberofdigits-numberofdigitsforrow;
                if (Emptyspace > 0)
                {
                    for (int b = 1; b <= Emptyspace/2; b++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");

                    }
                }
                for (int c = 1; c <= numberofdigitsforrow; c++)
                {
                    Console.Write(c.ToString());
                }
                if (Emptyspace > 0)
                {
                    for (int b = 1; b <= Emptyspace / 2; b++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: hope this will give resired results