# Trying to reverse/invert display of digit pyramid

Tags: android

My code below prints the following.

> ```
>        1
>       123
>      12345
>     1234567**
> ```

I want to to display this instead, but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

> ```
>      1234567
>       12345
>        123
>         1**
> ```

```
    int a = 1;
    int b = t5;
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= t5 ; i++) {
        for (int c = 1 ; c <= b - 1 ; c++) { 
            text.append("  ");
        }
        for (int k = 1 ; k <= a ; k++) {
            String result = String.valueOf(k);
            text.append(result);
        }
        a = a + 2;
        b--;
        text.append("\n");
    }
```

Comment: in pyramid/traingle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460804/print-reverse-pyramid-of-numbers

Comment: when I want code to perform some task, I make an attempt. So should you.....

Comment: Hi @MuhammadYasir - people like to see that you're stuck for legitimate reasons and to see you're trying. Can you edit your post or reply with what you think should happen and explain what you've tried, or ask about a specific thing you need to know so you can test some idea you have to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer i solved it

```
                    int b = t5 ;
                int a = 1;
                for (int i = b + 3 ; i > 0; i--) {
                    for (int c = 1 ; c <= a - 1 ; c++){
                        text.append("  ");
                    }
                    for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++) {
                        String result = String.valueOf(j);
                        text.append(result);
                    }
                    i = i - 1;
                    a++;
                    b--;
                    text.append("\n");
                }
```